Tokens created by 7 days
I'm just a data analysis student who needs to do college work.
I will write an article about MEMECOINS and their behavioral patterns, gains, losses, activity and the like.
What I need exactly is:
All token addresses created on Solana during the last 7 days. Just the address, after that I can use all the information I need to capture to get good insights and write a great article.
I'm trying to pull the data via FREE and I'm always getting access denied, is there any way for me to get this information?
